# How do I make a number variable from a html number input?

Tags: javascript, html, sum, integer

I am looking to add the values of two input elements (in this case sliders, but in future development one will probably become a number input) and add them together. This value I would like displayed on the console (again, in a later stage this will be a full-on part of the site using .innerHTML).

The code below treats the two values as text strings and just puts them next to each other (50+50=5050).
I've tried using .parseInt instead of .value but that did not help.

My HTML code:

```
    <input id="FirstSliderElement" type="range" min="0" max="100">
    <input id="SecondSliderElement" type="range" min="0" max="100">
    <button onclick="thisIsMyFunction()">Show in Console</button>
```

My JS code:

```
    var sliderOne = document.getElementById("FirstSliderElement");
    var sliderTwo = document.getElementById("SecondSliderElement");

    function thisIsMyFunction() {
        console.log("Slider One:", sliderOne.value)
        console.log("Slider Two:", sliderTwo.value)
        console.log("Sum:", sliderTwo.value + sliderOne.value)
}
```

Comment: As `parseInt` converts a string to a number under specific conditions only, we need to see the entered values, and also how exactly are you using `parseInt` when it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var sliderOne = document.getElementById("FirstSliderElement");
    var sliderTwo = document.getElementById("SecondSliderElement");

    function thisIsMyFunction() {
      let one1 = sliderOne.value ;
      one1 = parseInt(one1);
      let  two2 = sliderTwo.value ;
      two2 = parseInt(two2);
      
      console.log(two2 + one1 );
      
      // Your Code 
      
        console.log("Slider One:", sliderOne.value)
        console.log("Slider Two:", sliderTwo.value)
        console.log("Sum:", parseInt(sliderTwo.value) +
                            parseInt(sliderOne.value)
                   )
}
```

```html
<input id="FirstSliderElement" type="range" min="0" max="100">
    <input id="SecondSliderElement" type="range" min="0" max="100">
    <button onclick="thisIsMyFunction()">Show in Console</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `parseInt()` to parse any string that has a number;

Also there is no `.parseInt` on `document.getElementById("FirstSliderElement")`.

> `parseInt()` is a global **function**.

Check this to see the output for your code

```js
var sliderOne = document.getElementById("FirstSliderElement");
var sliderTwo = document.getElementById("SecondSliderElement");

function thisIsMyFunction() {
  var silderOneValue = parseInt(sliderOne.value);
  var silderTwoValue = parseInt(sliderTwo.value);

  console.log("Slider One:", silderOneValue)
  console.log("Slider Two:", silderTwoValue)
  console.log("Sum:", silderOneValue + silderTwoValue)
}
```

```html
<input id="FirstSliderElement" type="number" min="0" max="100">
<input id="SecondSliderElement" type="number" min="0" max="100">
<button onclick="thisIsMyFunction()">Show in Console</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `number` function to achieve that

from MDN - "The Number constructor contains constants and methods for working with numbers. **Values of other types can be converted to numbers using the Number() function**"

"When used as a function, Number(value) converts a string or other value to the Number type. If the value can't be converted, it returns NaN"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

```js
 var sliderOne = document.getElementById("FirstSliderElement");
    var sliderTwo = document.getElementById("SecondSliderElement");

    function thisIsMyFunction() {
        const value1 = Number(sliderOne.value);
        const value2 = Number(sliderTwo.value);
        console.log("Slider One:", value1)
        console.log("Slider Two:", value2)
        console.log("Sum:", value1 + value2)
}
```

```html
<input id="FirstSliderElement" type="number" min="0" max="100">
<input id="SecondSliderElement" type="number" min="0" max="100">
<button onclick="thisIsMyFunction()">Show in Console</button>
```

Comment: You might want to use unary `+` operator instead of the long version. But, OP has already stated, that they've tried to use `parseInt`, I can't see how this would fix their issue, as `parseInt` is essentially doing the same as `Number` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No need to parse when you can use `.valueAsNumber`

```js
var sliderOne = document.getElementById("FirstSliderElement");
var sliderTwo = document.getElementById("SecondSliderElement");

function thisIsMyFunction() {
  console.log("Slider One:", sliderOne.value);
  console.log("Slider Two:", sliderTwo.value);
  var sum = sliderTwo.valueAsNumber + sliderOne.valueAsNumber;
  console.log("Sum:", sum);
}
```

```html
<input id="FirstSliderElement" type="range" min="0" max="100">
<input id="SecondSliderElement" type="range" min="0" max="100">
<button onclick="thisIsMyFunction()">Show in Console</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let sliderOne = document.querySelector("#FirstSliderElement");
    let sliderTwo = document.querySelector("#SecondSliderElement");
    let btn = document.querySelector("#btn")

    btn.addEventListener("click", thisIsMyFunction)

    function thisIsMyFunction(){
        let sliderOneValue = parseInt(sliderOne.value);


        let sliderTwoValue = parseInt(sliderTwo.value);

        let add = sliderOneValue + sliderTwoValue;
        console.log(add)
    }
```